# Query ManagementScope object to find out Cache size in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching

I'm wanting to programmatically monitor the cache size on a certain ASP.NET site. This is basically for the administration portion of a product, where we allow users to partially control whether their site uses caching or not.

Is there a way to do this. Should I be using the ManagementScope object to perform this query?

Answer (score 0):

Is [Cache.EffectivePrivateBytesLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.effectiveprivatebyteslimit%28VS.80%29.aspx) what you're after?

Comment: That determines the maximum bytes allowable for the cache. I need the current cache size in memory.